# Sony Action Cam APIs for HDR-AS15 and HDR-AS30

Tags: android, sony

I've read the PDF files that came w/ the CameraRemoteAPIbeta_SDK_1.21 zip file and have a couple of questions:

1. Are both AS15 and AS30 controlled by the same API REST invocations? I'd like to buy just one of those cameras and develop for both.
2. My interests are remote controlling the camera to capture a movie through an app that I'm writing. . I see in the .pdf files that this is possible.

   - However, what I don't see in the API is how to download that last-recorded movie to my android tablet (or android phone) using the CameraRemoteAPIbeta_SDK_1.21 APIs. Is that possible to do through the API? I don't want my user-base to have to incorporate any other 3rd party app (that Sony supports directly or indirectly). Everything needs to be in my 1 .apk file.
   - What is the format of movies saved on the camera device itself?

Thank you for your support on these questions.
Jim

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your inquiry.

1) Yes, same application code can control both AS15 and AS30, but the capabilities of each Action Cam is different. Please check the API reference document for supported API groups.

2) The methods or APIs available at this time, are all listed in the API document. Please check the latest document at http://developer.sony.com  For the movie file formats available on each device, please check the device manuals at http://esupport.sony.com using the device model number.